# executing queries with a check constraint sql

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I created a SQL-Lite Database with a few tables in it.

```
TBL User:
UsrName PK

TBL Car
CarID PK
NotRentable BOOL

TBL CarUser
UsrName PK, FK CHECK(WHERE Car.CarID = CarID AND NotRentable = FALSE)
CarID PK, FK
```

Now I came across the possibility to have custom constraints on the to be created database entry using the "CHECK" keyword in different SQL dialects.

The examples the internet provides are more simple in the way that only the table that the entry should be written to can be queried using the CHECK keyword.

Is it possible to execute more complex sql-queries which evaluate as True or False as constraints before adding the new data to the table? This is a huge error source, but my intention would be to only use it for very basic matters. Like in the sample above! Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Not as queries, but you can do so using user-defined functions.

Comment: okay, that would include a switch in the database solution, but I will take a look into it anyway :) Sqlite is indeed very streamlined...

Comment: . . This is generally true across databases.  The `check` constraint is within a row.

Comment: Ah alright, the application must be enabled to do the mapping stuff then, Are User Defined Functions like preprocessors for queries? Given the parameters the script decides what to do next